# How to determine the time zone (EST,PST,MST,CST,AKST,HST) given a city,state in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime, rubygems, timezone

So I wrote a Ruby script such that given a city,state such as New York, NY you can get a time zone string such as "America/New York" returned.  I used the geocoder and timezone gems.  But is there an easy way (i.e., built-in function or library) to map "America/New York" to "EST"?  Mapping the city,state to EST/PST/etc is the real result I'm after.

Comment: Please clarify: you want to determine the time zone from the location (e.g. map New York, NY ---> time zone "America/New_York") or you want to determine what the short abbreviation is for a particular timezone (e.g. map time zone "America/New_York" ---> "EST" in the winter or "EDT" in the summer)? Your question title says you're after the time zone name ("America/New_York") but the last sentence suggests you want an abbreviation.

Comment: Also: If you want the abbreviations then I hope you're not planning to use those as keys/identifiers because they're not unique (for example "EST" is used by both "America/New_York" and "Australia/Sydney") and in many time zones they change twice a year (for example "America/New_York" uses both "EST" and "EDT")

Comment: I think we're missing something here. Why do you want to end up with the timezone name? What do you want to do with that?

Comment: You will have to do this by zip code since some states are split into multiple time-zones. [Indiana](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/us/indiana-time.html) is by far the worst.

Comment: @tadman - that information is already captured by the olson/tzdb timezone identifier.  [see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)  The abbreviations are also in the tzdb database, although I'm not sure if the ruby gem that the OP is using exposes it or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a Ruby programmer, but I do know that the abbreviation information you are looking for is included in the tzdb database.  I browsed through the source for the [TimeZone](https://github.com/panthomakos/timezone) ruby gem, but did not find anything on abbreviations, so my guess is that the author of that library did not think it was valuable so did not include it in the parser.  *(This is just an assumption.)*

I did find another Ruby implementation of the tzdb database called [TZInfo](http://tzinfo.rubyforge.org/), and it does appear to expose the abbreviation property for each zone.  You may want to investigate using that library instead.  I cannot offer specific advice as to which is better in general though.

As others warned in comments, be sure you are only using the abbreviation for display purposes.  It is only meaningful to humans, and only when they have some other context such as their location.  Worldwide, timezone abbreviations are not unique.  There is much ambiguity between them.  You can see a [full list here](http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/).